# Separating Game code and Engine code

Tags: opengl, sdl, data-structure

I've decided to take on a challenge of making 16 c++ games based on this [challenge](https://www.youtube.com/@FamTrinli) from FamTrinli, I'm using SDL + OpenGL. I've created a simple 2D game in the past, but I didn't like the code structure. My question is how should I separate the game code and engine code in a proper way. What functions should the engine class contain. Should the game be inherited from the engine class. Provide pictures if possible.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that every architectural decision must solve a practical problem. Start with no separation whatsoever (just different files for game and engine code, game repository is a fork of the engine repository), then, if that causes issues for some reason, move to a more complex model. Regarding game and engine classes - why do you think they need to be classes (as opposed to a namespace for the engine, and nothing for the game itself).

Comment: TLDR: Make at least 3 games and see what can be made common for them - that's your engine.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just followed the LearnOpenGL tutorial, but yeah a namespace would provide more reusability